# Mongoengine PointField gives location object expected, location array not in correct format error

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine, nosql

I have a model as follows:

```
class Station(Document):
    location = PointField()
```

Trying to write data as follows:

```
station = Station()
station.location = {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
      81.4471435546875,
      23.61432859499169
    ]
  }
station.save()
```

However this gives the error `Could not save document (location object expected, location array not in correct format)`

Mongoengine documentation says such a dictionary should be OK. What am I missing here?

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of mongoengine installed. Works on 0.8.4

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I had used GeoPointField first and then converted to PointField. I had dropped the data in the collection but not the collection itself, ehich created this problem.

Dropping the collection solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I face similar problem once, in my case it happens because i use GeoPointField to build the first prototype then move to PointField without dropping or migrating my database, for me, and because there were just dummy data in the db, the problem solves just after starting fresh my db doing a complete drop. I hope it can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue after converting some data from `GeoPointField` to `PointField` (using MongoEngine).

It was caused by the presence of two indexes. One for `GeoPointFIeld` and the other for `PointField`.  I dropped the first index and everything went fine.

You can check your indexes with `db.collection.getIndexes();` and then drop the index with `db.collection.dropIndex("index_name")`