# Data structure: mongoengine to GeoJson

Tags: django, metadata, mongoengine, geojson

I recently posted my first question on StackOverflow, but I think the question is quite extensive and full of potential errors. So I'd begin again, step-by-step, with a much shorter and simplier question :

Do you think this code is correct ?

**The purpose is to structure my models.py to store datas in my Mongo database as [GeoJson](http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html) objects.**

Thanks a lot !

---

### **models.py :**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from mongoengine import *
connect(‘mongodb_jsons’)

import datetime

class GeoJson(Document):
 # from a geojson object
 # save it in Mongodb with a geojson structure

    Date_created = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
    Location = PointField(auto_index=False) # as a list of 2 float numbers [ 10.000 , 240.000 ]
    Content1 = CharField()
    Content2 = CharField()

    meta = {'db_alias': 'mongodb_jsons', # save in DB ‘mongodb_jsons’
            'indexes': [                 # the geojson structure
                {'type' : 'Feature', {
                   'geometry':{
                        'type' : 'Point',
                        'coordinates' : ('Location', '2dsphere')
                        }, 
                   'properties':{
                       'content1' : 'Content1',
                       'content2' : 'Content2',    
                       'date_creation' : 'Date_created'
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
```

---

Comment: Are you getting errors with it?  Is there something it isn't doing?  I'm not sure what you are asking when you say "do you think this is correct?"  I don't know the problem you are trying to solve...so I have no idea if it meets your requirements correctly.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That won't work - you need a [2dsphere](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/#dsphere-indexes) index for geoJson in mongodb.  Why not use a [PointField](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.fields.PointField) as described in the [mongoengine documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/defining-documents.html?highlight=pointfield#geospatial-indexes).

Comment: My concern is that downstream I'll nedd to imitate the [GeoJson][1] structure to process it in my HTML template (it gonna be processed by the Leaflet library). I'm not sure about the 'meta' syntax. I changed the code in my question, do you think this would be working ?

Comment: PointField stores the data as valid `GeoJson` so you can use with `Doc.to_json()` to output a json string

Comment: did you see that ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22940168/how-to-format-data-for-mongoengine-pointfield